# Merge rows based on same column value (float type)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataset that looks like the following:

```
   id    name  phone  diagnosis
0   1  archie  12345    healthy
1   2   betty  23456       dead
2   3   clara  34567        NaN
3   3   clara  34567     kidney
4   4   diana  45678     cancer
```

I want to merge duplicated rows and have a table that looks like this:

```
   id    name  phone    diagnosis
0   1  archie  12345      healthy
1   2   betty  23456         dead
2   3   clara  34567  NaN, kidney
3   4   diana  45678       cancer
```

In short I want the entries in the diagnosis column put together so I can have an overview. I have tried running the following but it throws out an error, stating that a string was expected but a float was found.

```
data = data.groupby(['id','name','phone'])['diagnosis'].apply(', '.join).reset_index()
```

Anyone have any ideas how I can merge the rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of `NaN` values. And you can't really concatenate strings with `NaN` as expected. One alternative way is to fill nans with string 'NaN':

```
data.fillna('NaN', inplace=True)
data.groupby(['id', 'name', 'phone']).diagnosis.apply(', '.join).reset_index()
```

Comment: thanks! the solution worked, however I realised that there are values in the phone column that also need to be merged in the same fashion. any ideas how to attempt this for int values?

Comment: You can't apply join to `Int` as well. You may try something like `df.phone = df.phone.astype(str)
df.groupby('id').phone.agg(', '.join)`